# Why is values of a global variable returning blank when inserted into database

Tags: php

I am having an issue with using global variables to get values inserted into my custom database table:

```
// example that does not work 
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$mega = $user->user_login;   // this values will return blank when
                             // inserted into database especially 
                             // when used with an if statement.
```

The values work fine within the code in making a database query, but once inserted into the database it returns a blank empty value.

```
    // here is my full code
    global $wp;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $mega = $user->user_login;
    $age = 19;

    // if records were not found in the database 
    // then insert new row with the details
    if ( $age == 19) {
        $fillup = $wpdb->insert("markrecord_table", array(
            "username" => $mega,
            "post_id" => 340,
            "counted" => 1,
        )); 
    }
```

Comment: `wp_get_current_user()` shouldn't have a `$` at the beginning.

Comment: Your `if()` statement uses `=` (an [assignment operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)) instead of `==` or `===` ([comparison operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)). This can have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the updated code

```
// here is my full code
global $wpdb;
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$mega = $user->user_login;
$age = 19;

// if records were not found in the database 
// then insert new row with the details
if ( $age == 19) {
    $fillup = $wpdb->insert("markrecord_table", array(
        "username" => $mega,
        "post_id" => 340,
        "counted" => 1,
    )); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,  @Pat J  you pointed out the real issue, i shoud have used if ($age == 19) that comparison operator == fixed the issue and have updated my code above